# Best way to include sub-templates into templates in Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm writing webapp using Spring 3 MVC with annotations. I use jsp for view layer. I have a few basic templates and many templates that I want to include into this basic templates in depend of controller.

I know that I can add template name to model inside controller, but it is not best way I think. I think some declarative way must exists.

What the best way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try [Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/) ([integration with Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-tiles), [petcare sample](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petcare/trunk/)).

With Tiles you can break your templates into subtemplates, assemble them declaratively into tiles' definitions and use definition names as view names returned from controllers.

Comment: Thanks, but I seek for more lightweight approach. To use Tiles, I must learn how to use it, before.

Comment: I have take a quick look at Tiles - it really simple to use. Thanks